# ECONNREFUSED : Communication between two docker containers in same docker network not working

Tags: node.js, docker

Hi I have two Docker containers running which has node application in it, so that means I am trying to communicate between two node application running in seperate environments.
Both of these containers are in same network called `my-network`.I tried entering inside the container using `docker exec -it <container-name-or-id> /bin/bash` and running `ping` to the other container. It seems like both containers are accessible to each other, but when I tried to connect to the other container inside the node application using `request module` with `hostname` as `<other-container-name>`.

Now I get the following error: 
`Error: connect ECONNREFUSED x.x.x.x:xxxx`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you paste the command you use to run the two containers?

Comment: When you say `<other-container-name>` are you talking about the name given via `--name` parameter passed to `docker run`? That would not be the hostname of the container. You would have to explicitly pass a hostname using -h or you would have to take the hash of the container which is by default the hostname of the container.

Comment: yes I have used the name mentioned using `hostname` in docker-compose file .

Comment: can you share the docker-compose file?

Comment: I have got it working , Thanks alot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue  for my problem. 
Actually in my `docker-compose.yml` I have three services mentioned :

1. node-app-1
2. node-app-2
3. mysql

Here container node-app-1 is trying to communicate to the container node-app- which must have a node express server running and listening to sepcific port x.x.x.x . But application in node-app-2 was trying to ccreate connection with the mysql container for database access.Due to password specific reason it wasn't able to connect to connect to mysql and hence the express application in it was crashing and the server inside wasn't listening at that mentioned port.
So when container node-app-1 tried to connect to other container, It threw an error , `connection refused`